# SharePoint 2003 and Office 2010 - Multiple upload error

Tags: file-upload, 2003, office-integration

my problem is that I can not upload documents to SharePoint 2003 when I using the multiple upload.
(Only the multiple upload is not working, when I push the button nothing happens)

I had no problems with the multiple document upload when I used a SharePoint 2010 environment.

Comment: Nothing in SP Logs or event lots?

Comment: Do you mean that the actual uploader doesn't show up, or that you manage to add files, but when you press the button to start the upload - nothing happens?

Comment: What browser are you using?  Could be a client side issue.

Comment: Windows XP, IE 8. My opinion is also that this is a client side issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you really do mean SharePoint 2003 and not 2007?

In 2007, there's some script which runs on click of the multiple item upload link. It sounds to me like that script isn't firing. I'd try a little debugging in the browser with IE's Developer Tools or in Firefox with Firebug to see if there is indeed a script problem. If there is, it may be caused by some other scripting component you have added interfering.